# Getting Latitude and Longitude from a Linestring

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0, postgis-1.5

I have a linestring geometry in my Postgres database. I wanted to extract the latitude-longitude coordinates of each point inside the linestring. Example

```
 "0102000020E610000002000000CCDA5CEB41D323406E2A9CEE86C54A40CCDA5CEB41D323406E2A9CEE86C54A40"
"0102000020E610000002000000AF5FB01BB6CD22407C7E18213C8E4A40AF5FB01BB6CD22407C7E18213C8E4A40"
```

Till now, I have executed the query

```
SELECT st_astext(geometry) from warning_vmz;
```

result

```
"LINESTRING(7.17999 52.66463,7.17899 52.66563,7.17857 52.66604)"
"LINESTRING(7.2860666 53.1664885,7.2860666 53.1664885)"
```

so I have tried the another function

```
Select ST_DumpPoints(ST_GeomFromText(st_astext(geometry))) from warning_vmz;
```

output

```
"({1},01010000004C89247A19652240E8A4F78DAF8D4A40)"
"({2},010100000012BD8C62B965224076543541D48D4A40)"
```

If I use ST_DumpPoints(ST_GeomFromText(geometry)) then I get an error

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "0102000020E6100000711300004C" <-- parse error at position 28 within geometry
********** Error **********
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a syntax error, try this:

`SELECT st_astext(((ST_Dumppoints (geometry)).geom)) as geom from warning_vmz;`

note that this line is incorrect, "LINESTRING(7.2860666 53.1664885,7.2860666 53.1664885)"
it is wrong,
to add the new request to check the geometry for errors [Why can PostGIS create LINESTRING from the same values of coordinates of the POINT type?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284733/why-can-postgis-create-linestring-from-the-same-values-of-coordinates-of-the-poi)

Comment: I'm happy for you, keep trying...

Comment: Thank you, SELECT st_astext(((ST_Dumppoints (geometry)).geom)) as geom from warning_vmz; gives all coordinates from linestring, how can I filter points for each linestring?

Comment: try group by id, it should work

Comment: I have accepted the answer, thank you. I wanted to create a grid of geographical coordinates 52.36, 9.8 with a distance of 1 km and trying to represent these point, can you please suggest some lead? I am stuck.

Comment: Look at this answer - https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271234/creating-a-grid-on-a-polygon-and-find-number-of-points-in-each-grid/284894#284894 it will help you solve your problem or look for similar answers, there are enough of them...